# Mostrar qué números son capicúas de una lista de entrada

Tags: java

**Descripción**

Dado un lote de n números mostrar cuantos números son palíndromos utilizar almenos una función o procedimiento para realizar el ejercicio

**Entrada**

El problema tiene vario casos de prueba y termina cuando no hay mas datos. Se debe leer un numero `n` de entrada el cual define cuantos números `t` habrán para ser trabajados, la entrada termina cuando no haya mas datos que leer.

**Salida**

Por cada numero `n` leído de teclado debe haber una salida que indique cuantos números `t` son palindromos.

**Ejemplo Entrada**

```
5
131
645
1122
334433
13322
```

**Ejemplo Salida**

```
2
```

Mi código es este:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejrcB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lee= new Scanner(System.in);
        long n2 ;
        n2 = lee.nextLong();
        int r,s=0,k,num = 0,con=0;
        k=(int) n2;

        while (num<=n2-1) {
            num++;
            long n1 = lee.nextLong();
            k=(int) n1;

            while(n1!=0){    
                r=(int) (n1%10);
                s=s*10+r;
                n1=n1/10;
            }
            if(s==k) {
                con++; 
            }
            s=s*0;
        }
        System.out.println(con);
    }
}
```

Pero al enviar el código al juez me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: da la impresion de que solo falta agregar un ciclo que contenga todo el codigo para que funcione para `N` casos de prueba. Tambien deberias crear mas metodos que se encarguen de funcionalidades especificas como por ejemplo un metodo para verificar si una entrada es palindrome

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice Klaimmore, lo que te falta es un bucle exterior que se mantenga a la espera de mas lecturas, para que así, cuando se cumple la condición de salida de tu actual primer bucle (`while (num<=n2-1) {`), se pueda leer la siguiente entrada.

Así cuando el primer set de números acaba (11) tu programa no sigue leyendo, pero debería hacerlo, ya que puede haber mas (y este caso, los hay)

Comment: La respuesta debería incluir como realizar dicho bucle, esto es más bien un comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Pongo aquí el código necesario para completar lo que se necesita:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MiPrueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lee= new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> salida =new ArrayList<Integer>();
        long n2 ;
    long res=0;
    while (lee.hasNext()){
           n2 = lee.nextLong();
           int r,s=0,k,num = 0,con=0;
           k=(int) n2;

           while (num<=n2-1) {
               num++;

               long n1 = lee.nextLong();
               k=(int) n1;

               while(n1!=0){    
                   r=(int) (n1%10);
                   s=s*10+r;
                   n1=n1/10;
               }
               if(s==k) {
                   con++; 
               }
               s=s*0;
           }
       salida.add(con);
       res++;
    }
        Iterator<Integer> nombreIterator = salida.iterator();
    while(nombreIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(nombreIterator.next());
    }


    }
}
```